# Is a CMS appropriate for expense tracking website?

Tags: php, joomla

I am in the initial stages of developing a website to track expenses that should have the following functionality:

-users can create an account

-users have their own admin section in which they can...

-create categories such as 'doctor visit', 'drugs', 'home visit', etc.

-for each category, user can enter a date and cost

In essence, the website should enable users to track how much money they are spending per month on several aspects of health care. It would be similar in structure to, for example, www.dailyburn.com (where you create your account and can track your meal calories, minutes of exercise etc).

Would CMSs like Joomla, Drupal be appropriate for this job?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendations on developing website to track health care costs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800393/recommendations-on-developing-website-to-track-health-care-costs). Please don't repost questions. Your original is likely to be reopened.

Comment: Since the other question is still closed.. the answer is no. No CMS is going to do this out of the box.  You can tweak it and bash it to fit your end goals, but you're going to have to dig into it and do some coding either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal or Joomla are both capable of doing what your asking but, like anything, if you've never used them before there's a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: thanks jwerre - re the feature in which the user has his own account/admin section: do you know if this something that would require coding from the grund up or are there modules that enable this? I have a lot of experience with Magento - which I know is a very different animal - but for example it already has out of the box an admin area for registered users to check their orders, newsletter subscriptions etc. Anything similar with these CMSs?